# Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad. Admob

Tags: java, android

When I install the game on my phone and I wanna run my app I see in LogCat a message with "Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad."

MainActivity.java

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

activity_main.xml

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scroll view has 'fill_parent' value. Try to put yiur banner in the top of your page or use fragment layout